# How do I have an array parameter that takes input from the args or the pipeline in Powershell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, pipeline

I'm trying to write a Powershell function that takes an array argument. I want it to be called with the array either as an argument, or as pipeline input. So, calling looks something like this:

```
my-function -arg 1,2,3,4
my-function 1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4 | my-function
```

It's easy enough to get the first two:

```
function my-function {
    param([string[]]$arg)
    $arg
}
```

For pipeline input, though, it's harder. It's easy to get the arguments one at a time in the process block, by using ValueFromPipeline, but that means that the $args variable is a single value with pipeline input, but an array if -args is used. I can use $input in the END block, but that doesn't get -args input at all, and using $args in an END block only gets the final item from a pipeline.

I suppose that I can do this by explicitly collecting the argument values from the pipeline using begin/process/end blocks, as follows:

```
function my-function {
    param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)][string[]]$args)

    begin {
        $a = @()
    }
    process {
        $a += $args
    }

    end {
        # Process array here
        $a -join ':'
    }
}
```

But that seems very messy. It also seems like a relatively common requirement to me, so I was expecting it to be easy to implement. Is there an easier way that I have missed? Or if not, is there a way to encapsulate the argument handling into a sub-function, so that I don't have to include all that in every function I want to work like this?

My concrete requirement is that I'm writing scripts that take SQL commands as input. Because SQL can be verbose, I want to allow for the possibility of piping in the command (maybe generated by another command, or from get-contents on a file) but also allow for an argument form, for a quick SELECT statement. So I get a series of strings from the pipeline, or as a parameter. If I get an array, I just want to join it with "`n" to make a single string - line by line processing is not appropriate.

I guess another question would be, is there a better design for my script that makes getting multi-line input like this cleaner?

---

Thanks - the trick is NOT to use ValueFromPipeline then...

The reason I was having so much trouble getting things to work the way I wanted was that in my test scripts, I was using $args as the name of my argument variable, forgetting that it is an automatic variable. So things were working very oddly...

```
PS> 1,2,3,4 | ./args

PS> get-content args.ps1
param([string[]]$args)

if ($null -eq $args) { $args = @($input) }
$args -join ':'
```

Doh :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the automatic variable `$input`.

If only pipeline input is expected then:

```
function my-function {
    $arg = @($input)
    $arg
}
```

But I often use this combined approach (a function that accepts input both as an argument or via pipeline):

```
function my-function {
    param([string[]]$arg)

    # if $arg is $null assume data are piped
    if ($null -eq $arg) {
        $arg = @($input)
    }

    $arg
}


# test
my-function 1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4 | my-function
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's another example using Powershell 2.0+

This example is if the parameter is not required:

```
function my-function {
  [cmdletbinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
    [string[]]$Names
  )

  End {
    # Verify pipe by Counting input
    $list = @($input)
    $Names = if($list.Count) { $list } 
      elseif(!$Names) { @(<InsertDefaultValueHere>) } 
      else { @($Names) }

    $Names -join ':'
  }
}
```

There's one case where it would error out without the 'elseif'. If no value was supplied for Names, then $Names variable will not exist and there'd be problems. See this [link](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/down-the-rabbit-hole--a-study-in-powershell-pipelines,-functions,-and-parameters/) for explanation.

If it is required, then it doesn't have to be as complicated.

```
function my-function {
  [cmdletbinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
    [string[]]$Names
  )

  End {
    # Verify pipe by Counting input
    $list = @($input)
    if($list.Count) { $Names = $list } 

    $Names -join ':'
  }
}
```

It works, exactly as expected and I now I always reference that link when writing my Piped Functions.

Answer (score 1):

### ValueFromPipeline

You *should* use the pipeline (ValueFromPipeline) as PowerShell is specially designed for it.

### $args

First of all, there is no real difference between:
`my-function -<ParamName> 1,2,3,4` and
`my-function 1,2,3,4` (assuming that the parameter `$ParamName` is at the first position).

The point is that the parameter name `$args` is just an unfortunate choice as [`$args`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6#args) is an automatic variable and therefore shouldn't be used for a parameter name. Almost any other name (that is not in the [automatic variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6) list) should do as in the example from [Sean M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3749832/sean-m), but instead you should implement your cmdlet assuming that it will be called from the middle of a pipeline (see: [Strongly Encouraged Development Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd878270(v=vs.85).aspx)).
<sub>(And if you want to do this completely right, you should give a singular name, plural parameter names should be used only in those cases where the value of the parameter is *always* a multiple-element value.)</sub>

### Middle

The supposed cmdlet in your question is not a very good example as it only cares about the input and has a single output therefore I have created another example:

```
Function Create-Object {
    Param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)][String[]]$Name)
    Begin {
        $Batch = 0
        $Index = 0
    }
    Process {
        $Batch++
        $Name | ForEach {
            $Index++
            [PSCustomObject]@{'Name' = $_; 'Index' = $Index; 'Batch' = $Batch}
        }
    }
}
```

It basically creates custom objects out of a list of names (`$Names = "Adam", "Ben", "Carry"`).
This happens when you supply the '$Names` via an argument:

```
Create-Object $Names

Name  Index Batch
----  ----- -----
Adam      1     1
Ben       2     1
Carry     3     1
```

(It iterates through all the names in `$Name` parameter using the `ForEach` cmdlet.)

And this happens when you supply the `$Names` via the pipeline:

```
$Names | Create-Object

Name  Index Batch
----  ----- -----
Adam      1     1
Ben       2     2
Carry     3     3
```

Note that the output is quiet similar (if it wasn't for the `batch` column, the output is in fact the same) but the objects are now created in 3 separate batches meaning that every item is iterated at the `process` method and the `ForEach` loop only iterates ones every batch because the `$Name` parameter contains an array with *one* single item each `process` iteration.

### Use case

Imaging that the `$Names` come from a slow source (e.g. a different threat, or a remote database). In the case you using the pipeline for processing the `$Names` your cmdlet can start processing the `$Names` (and pass the new objects onto the next cmdlet) even if not all `$Names` are available yet. In comparison to providing the `$Names` via an argument were all the `$Names` will need to be collected first before your cmdlet will process them and pass the new objects onto the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by using the [input processing methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.1#input-processing-methods) `BEGIN`, `PROCESS`, and `END` blocks. I just ran into this. Here is my console output just playing around with this and you can see by putting the body of the function in the `PROCESS` block it behaves the way you would expect

### Not working

```
λ ~ function test-pipe {
>>     param (
>>         # Parameter help description
>>         [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
>>         [String[]]
>>         $Texts
>>     )
>>     $Texts | % {Write-Host $_}
>> }
λ ~ "this", "that", "another"
this
that
another
λ ~ $s = @("this", "that", "another")
λ ~ $s
this
that
another
λ ~ $s | test-pipe
another
λ ~ test-pipe -Texts $s
this
that
another
```

### Working

```
λ ~ function test-pipe {
>>     param (
>>         # Parameter help description
>>         [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
>>         [String[]]
>>         $Texts
>>     )
>>     BEGIN {}
>>     PROCESS {$Texts | % {Write-Host $_}}
>>     END {}
>>
>> }
λ ~ $s | test-pipe
this
that
another
λ ~
```