# what's the current best-practice in powershell 5.1 for pipeline parameters that are also arrays?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I know a way to do pipeline parameters that are also arrays in Powershell functions, but it's very verbose:

```ps
function invoke-exampleFunctionWithPipelineArrayParameter {
  param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)][string[]]$myInput)
  begin {
    $isFromPipeline = -not $PSBoundParameters["myInput"]
    $collected = $(if($isFromPipeline) {,[Collections.ArrayList]::new()} else {$null})
  }
  process {
    if($isFromPipeline) {
      $collected.Add($myInput) | out-null
    } else {
      $collected = $myInput
    }

    $myInput | foreach-object {
      Write-Output "Do something to each input. write element: $_"
    }
  }
  end {
    Write-Output "Do something to total array collected. write count: $(($collected | Measure-Object).Count)"
  }
}

Write-host "pipline"
1,2,3 | invoke-exampleFunctionWithPipelineArrayParameter

Write-host "parameter"
invoke-exampleFunctionWithPipelineArrayParameter a,b,c,d
```

yields

```txt
pipline
Do something to each input. write element: 1
Do something to each input. write element: 2
Do something to each input. write element: 3
Do something to total array collected. write count: 3
parameter
Do something to each input. write element: a
Do something to each input. write element: b
Do something to each input. write element: c
Do something to each input. write element: d
Do something to total array collected. write count: 4
```

as you can see, there's a lot of ceremony and boilerplate there for such a common use-case.  I've seen advice similar to this across SO (see [How do I have an array parameter that takes input from the args or the pipeline in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435613/how-do-i-have-an-array-parameter-that-takes-input-from-the-args-or-the-pipeline) for an example), but often it's very old advice.  PS has evolved since then - even PS5.1, not just PS7.  Is this still the best way to do this common case?

Comment: It depends on use-case, if im understanding you correctly.  There really isn't anything wrong with just iterating through the input like you're doing so in the process block as well. As for saving it to an array, you can assign it directly to a variable: `$collection = foreach ($item in $MyInput) { ... }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complement [iRon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77248776/45375) with **performance considerations**:

Indeed, no extra effort is required for handling the `$InputObject` parameter value in your `process` block, as long as you *enumerate* it there in order to process its elements.

However, it's important to note that **by declaring your pipeline-binding parameters as an *array* (`[string[]]`)**, you're:

- optimizing for invocation by *direct argument*, i.e. via explicit use of the `-InputObject` parameter...

  ```bash
  # @('foo') * 1000 creates a 1000-element array of 'foo' strings.
  Invoke-ExampleFunctionWithPipelineArrayParameter -InputObject (@('foo') * 1000)
  ```
- ... but **slowing down *pipeline*-input processing**

  ```bash
  (@('foo') * 1000) | Invoke-ExampleFunctionWithPipelineArrayParameter
  ```

The reason is that in pipeline processing - where only a *single* string is passed at a time (because the input array is *enumerated* in the pipeline) - *each such string is converted to a single-element array* due to the target parameter's date type; additionally, it introduces the need to *enumerate* each `$InputObject` value.

See the bottom section for benchmarks that gauge the performance impact.
The short of it:

- At least in *PowerShell* code, the **slowdown isn't dramatic**, so you may still choose to use array-typed parameters.

---

To **avoid this slow-down**, you have only two options, both of which involve **trade-offs**:

- *Either*: Declare your pipeline-binding parameters as a *scalar* (non-array) and thereby **forgo support for passing input *by argument***.

  ```bash
  [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
  [string] $myInput  # [string] *scalar*
  ```

  - That is, you then won't be able to pass an *array* to `-InputObject`, making direct use of the parameter useless.
  - This is the trade-off made by *most* cmdlets, with a few high-profile exceptions, such as `Set-Content` and `Out-File`; see the discussion in [GitHub issue #4242](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4242).
  - Inside your `process` block, you can then work with `$InputObject` *directly* - no need for enumeration.
- *Or*: **Forgo *strict typing***, i.e. type your pipeline-binding parameter as `[object]` (which is the same as not typing it), which therefore allows both scalars and arrays to bind to it.

  ```bash
  [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
  [object] $myInput  # Now either a scalar or an array can bind
  ```

  - *Caveat*: Unless your function *of conceptual necessity* requires `[object]`-typed input, you may need to enforce the desired type via runtime checks (e.g. `-is [string]`), which can negate the performance benefits of not using a strongly typed *array* parameter to begin with.
  - Given that `$InputObject` is by definition already in memory in full, the fastest way to enumerate it in your `process` block is to use a `foreach` *statement* (rather than a nested `ForEach-Object` pipeline):

    ```bash
    process {
      foreach ($object in $InputObject) { <# work with $object #> }
    }
    ```
- If you need to (also) ***collect* all input via the `process` block, in order to then process *all* objects in the `end` block** (notably for functionality such as sorting and grouping, where *item-by-item* processing isn't an option), you can use the following idiom, which is similar to your original approach:

  ```bash
  function Invoke-ExampleFunctionWithPipelineArrayParameter {
    param   (
      [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] [object] $InputObject
    )
    begin { 
      $fromPipeline = $MyInvocation.ExpectingInput
      $data = 
       if ($fromPipeline) { , [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new() }
       else               { $InputObject }
    }
    process { 
      # NOTE: If $InputObject is *array*-typed, use $data.AddRange($InputObject) instead.
      if ($fromPipeline) { $data.Add($InputObject) }
    }
    end {
      # ... work with $data, which now contains all input objects, whether
      #     from the pipeline or by direct argument.
      [pscustomobject] @{
        CountOfObjectsReceived = $data.Count
        Objects = $data
      }
    }
  }
  ```

  - `$MyInvocation.ExpectingInput` is used to determine if pipeline input is being provided,
  - A [`` System.Collections.Generic.List`1 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.List-1) instance is used to collect the objects.

    - Aside from offering strong typing (which isn't needed here), the latter's `.Add()` method sensibly has no return value.

      - Neither does the `.AddRange()` method, which you need to use instead if `$InputObject` is *array*-typed; also, you would then declare your list with that array's element type; e.g., for `[string[]]`, you'd declare `[System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()`
    - By contrast, [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ArrayList)'s `.Add()` method does have a return value, which is a frequent source of accidental output-stream pollution. Additionally, the linked docs effectively declare the type (soft-)*deprecated*: "We don't recommend that you use the ArrayList class for new development."

---

##### Benchmarks:

- Below are sample timings **comparing pipeline processing with array- vs. scalar-typed parameters vs. by-argument processing** for 100,000 input objects, averaged over 10 runs.
- Timing commands is never an exact science in PowerShell, and performance varies based on many factors, not least the hardware with respect to *absolute* times, but the results below provide a sense of *relative* performance, as reflected in the `Factor` output column: `1.00` denotes the fastest command, listed first, with the slower ones expressed as multiples of it, in descending order of speed.
- The bottom sections contains the source code, allowing you to run these benchmarks yourself

  - For best results, run the benchmarks while your machine isn't (too) busy doing other things.

Windows PowerShell 5.1 on Windows 11 sample results:

```
Factor Secs (10-run avg.) Command                                                              TimeSpan
------ ------------------ -------                                                              --------
1.00   0.014              Invoke-ExampleFunctionWithPipelineArrayParameter -InputObject $array 00:00:00.0141027
10.62  0.150              $array | Invoke-ExampleFunctionWithPipelineScalarParameter           00:00:00.1497940
13.48  0.190              $array | Invoke-ExampleFunctionWithPipelineArrayParameter            00:00:00.1900570
```

[PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) 7.3.7 on Windows 11 sample results:

```
Factor Secs (10-run avg.) Command                                                              TimeSpan
------ ------------------ -------                                                              --------
1.00   0.007              Invoke-ExampleFunctionWithPipelineArrayParameter -InputObject $array 00:00:00.0074160
10.58  0.078              $array | Invoke-ExampleFunctionWithPipelineScalarParameter           00:00:00.0784701
13.83  0.103              $array | Invoke-ExampleFunctionWithPipelineArrayParameter            00:00:00.1025566
```

**Findings**:

- By-argument passing is faster by a factor of about 10 compared to scalar pipeline processing.
- An array-typed pipeline-binding parameter slows down processing by about 30% compared to a scalar parameters.
- PowerShell (Core) is faster than Windows PowerShell.

**Benchmark source code**:

- The following benchmark code uses function `Time-Command` from [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/9e1f13978620b09ab2d15da5535d1b27).
- Unless already present, you are prompted to automatically download and define this function in your session. (I can personally assure you that doing so is safe, but you should always check the source code yourself.)

````bash
# Download and define function `Time-Command` on demand (will prompt).
# To be safe, inspect the source code at the specified URL first.
if (-not (Get-Command -ErrorAction Ignore Time-Command)) {
  $gistUrl = 'https://gist.github.com/mklement0/9e1f13978620b09ab2d15da5535d1b27/raw/Time-Command.ps1'
  if ((Read-Host "`n====`n  OK to download and define benchmark function ``Time-Command```n  from Gist ${gistUrl}?`n=====`n(y/n)?").Trim() -notin 'y', 'yes') { Write-Warning 'Aborted.'; exit 2 }
  Invoke-RestMethod $gistUrl | Invoke-Expression 3>$null
  if (-not ${function:Time-Command}) { exit 2 }
}

# Sample input array with 100,0000 elements.
$array = @('foo') * 1e5

# Sample functions
function Invoke-ExampleFunctionWithPipelineArrayParameter {
  param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] [string[]] $InputObject)
  process { foreach ($o in $InputObject) { $o } } # $InputObject needs enumeration.
}

function Invoke-ExampleFunctionWithPipelineScalarParameter {
  param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] [string] $InputObject)
  process { $InputObject } # No need for enumeration
}

# Define script blocks with the commands to time.
$commands = @(
  {
    $array | Invoke-ExampleFunctionWithPipelineArrayParameter
  }

  {
    $array | Invoke-ExampleFunctionWithPipelineScalarParameter
  } 

  {
    Invoke-ExampleFunctionWithPipelineArrayParameter -InputObject $array
  } 
)

Write-Verbose -Verbose 'Running benchmarks...'

# Note: To print command output, add -OutputToHost
Time-Command -Count 10 $commands
````

Comment: Wow, that's thorough.  A question -- I noticed that PowerShell converts empty arraylist to $null in the if-as-expression thing if you don't do the unary-comma operator.  Does it not do that to the generic list collection?

Comment: @Pxtl, thanks for catching that - yes, with `if` you do need the unary `,` (I originally used `$data = $fromPipeline ? [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new() : $InputObject`, in which case you do _not_ need it, but this operator is PSv7+ only). I've fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for all that `$isFromPipeline` hassle.

- If you don't pipe any pipeline input, PowerShell still processes the `Process` block just once where the `ValueFromPipeline` parameter  (`$myInput`) contains *all* items.
- If you do pipe any input, PowerShell processes each single input item -also contained in the `ValueFromPipeline` parameter  (`$myInput`) variable- in the  `Process` block.

```bash
function invoke-exampleFunctionWithPipelineArrayParameter {
  param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)][string[]]$myInput)
  process {
    $myInput | ForEach-Object { $_ }
  }
}

1,2,3 | invoke-exampleFunctionWithPipelineArrayParameter
1
2
3

invoke-exampleFunctionWithPipelineArrayParameter a,b,c,d
a
b
c
d
```

- Only when you pass an **empty array** (an [AutomationNull](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-null#empty-null)) the `Process` block is skipped:

  ```bash
  @() | invoke-exampleFunctionWithPipelineArrayParameter a,b,c,d
  ```

Comment: Nicely done; quibble: it isn't just arrays: any empty enumerable that PowerShell treats as such results in skipping the `process` block. It's hard to come up with a succinct description, though: Types that implement the `IEnumerable` interface or its generic counterpart are enumerated, but there are a few exceptions: strings, dictionaries (types implementing `IDictionary` or its generic counterpart), and `System.Xml.XmlNode` instances. Additionally, `System.Data.DataTable` is enumerated, via its `.Rows` property.

Comment: Sorry but "do something with total array collected" was not decorative.  Sometimes that stuff provides important optimizations where doing objects one-at-a-time will have dire performance.

Comment: Your question didn't mention anything about performance, just best practice where the general advise is: [Script authors are advised to use idiomatic PowerShell unless performance dictates otherwise](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/performance/script-authoring-considerations) and cleared by the helpful answer and benchmarks from @mklement0. Note that the PowerShell Pipeline is often underestimated in performance where you probably want to [look at the full solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59437162/1701026) and also (memory) usage.